# Characterization of weakly compact operators

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, continuity, weak-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces, I've read that if $T:X^*\to Y$ is a bounded linear operator such that $T^*(Y^*)\subset X$ then $T$ is weak*-to-weak continuous.

**First question**. Does $T^*(Y^*)\subset X$ mean to be $T^*(Y^*)\subset J_X(X)$, where $J_X$ is the canonical embedding from $X$ to $X^{**}$?

**Second question**. Why should be such an operator weak*-to-weak continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_i^{*} \to x^{*}$ in weak* topology of $X^{*}$ then $(Tx_i^{*}) (y^{*})=x_i^{*}(T^{*}(y^{*})) \to x^{*}(T^{*}(y^{*}))=(T^{*}x^{*})(y^{*})$ for all $y^{*}$, so $Tx_i^{*} \to Tx^{*}$ in weak topology.

Since these topologies are not metrizable you have to use nets rather than sequences.

[$x_i^{*}(T^{*}(y^{*})) \to x^{*}(T^{*}(y^{*}))$ follows from the hypothesis that $T^{*}(Y^{*}) \subseteq X$].

Comment: By $(Tx_i^*)(y^*)$ do you mean $\langle Tx_i^*, y^* \rangle= (y^*)(Tx_i^*)$ right? And, would you answer my first question? It is $T^*(Y^*)\subset X$ a way to say $T^*(Y^*)\subset J(X)$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is customery to idenitfy $Jx$ with $x$ itself and write $J(x) (x^{*})$ as just $x(x^{*})\equiv x^{*}(x)$. @Psaro